How to delay or slow down rot in deck post?
My deck is almost 7 years old.
I was concern about rotting in deck post.
So i did dig carefully around one of the deck post for 6-8 inches down and i think i didnt see sign of rot yet. This post set in concrete not all the way up.
What is right way to fill this post back to delay or slow down the rot?


Fill the hole back in. Then ensure that there's good drainage away from the house and, therefore, away from the post.

Fill with concrete mix raise 2-3  from the ground level.?

Turn the surrounding two feet of clay into gravel, leaving room for a few inches of top soil.

Do not  use cement if the drainage around the post is not exceptionally good.  Cement will hold moisture around the post and cause it to rot faster. Gravel and sand, then topsoil is the best solution.

Thanks everyone.
